# is there anyway to achieve the mvc pattern in flutter developpment without using the getx package

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-getx

is there any way to achieve a better approach for the **MVC, Model-View-Pattern** architecture pattern, without using the `Getx` flutter package?

since the Getx package is just a lot, and I don(t want to use it's other features but the state management

is there any packages or some ways that help manage my app state with **MVC**

any information are welcome

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of state management solutions for flutter just a Google search (or stackoverflow search) away.

You would find this pretty much straight away:

https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options

Comment: thank you, but no package seems to give the possibility to achieve an MVC pattern, there is some good packages out there, bloc, provider, and redux..., but I can't use them with the MVC architecture pattern on my project

Answer (score 1):

Did you already try [get_cli](https://pub.dev/packages/get_cli)? The official CLI for the GetX™ framework. This helps expeditious development with [GetX](https://pub.dev/packages/get). It has two patterns to choose from

1. GetX Pattern - MVC
2. CLEAN by Arktekko - Clean Architecture

Comment: Hi, I already use it, but it was made for Getx, I'm searching for other alternatives